# Overwrite file in Mobile Documents

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a file stored in the current location on my phone:

```
/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~is~workflow~my~workflows/Documents/File.JSON
```

Now, I have created a new JSON file that I want to replace it with, like this:

```
    let jsonObject: [String: Any] = [
        "ID": "819736471902",
        "TOKEN": "w5tw905y3475n30984um0f2ur0283urn27y4brt38t209"
    ]

    let valid = JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(jsonObject) // true
    
    print(valid)
    print("...")
    print(jsonObject)
    
    let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject)
```

I am going to use the same file name and the same location, so I just want to replace the old file with this new one.

I know I can now save this file using the `UIDocumentPickerViewController`, but is there any other way I can do this saving process in the background?

Answer (score 0):

You can change to use `FileManager` to saving json in background

Code will be like this

```swift
func saveJson(fileName: String, json: [String: Any]) {
    // get documentary path to save image to
    guard let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return }

    let fileName = fileName
    let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    
    let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)

    //Checks if file exists, removes it if so.
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: fileURL.path)
            print("Removed old file")
        } catch let removeError {
            print("couldn't remove file at path", removeError)
        }
    }
    
    do {
        try jsonData.write(to: fileURL)
    } catch let error {
        print("error saving file with error", error)
    }
}

func loadJsonFromDiskWith(fileName: String) -> [String: Any] {
  let documentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory

    let userDomainMask = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(documentDirectory, userDomainMask, true)

    if let dirPath = paths.first {
        let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: fileURL.path))
            let dict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
            return dict as! [String : Any]
        } catch {
            return [:]
        }
    }
    return [:]
}
```

Usage

```swift
let jsonObject: [String: Any] = [
    "ID": "819736471902",
    "TOKEN": "w5tw905y3475n30984um0f2ur0283urn27y4brt38t209"
]

self.saveJson(fileName: "abc.json", json: jsonObject)
let finalDict = self.loadJsonFromDiskWith(fileName: "abc.json")
print(finalDict) // your json from store in Document
```

Comment: It's still in the wrong directory. When I print out `print("Removed old file: \(fileURL)")`, it gives me this location: `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/BCFE1C34-49A7-4ADF-860C-A8618B628376/Documents/File.JSON`. And also `print("Write to: \(fileURL)")` gives me the same path, but the correct path should be: `/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~is~workflow~my~workflows/Documents/File.JSON`.